# ActionBarSherlock usage - personal or commercial products

Tags: android

Can actionbarsherlock be used in amy commercial production? Can someone help me to go through license of ActionBarSherlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is Apache license.**

It means you have to mention in your application that you have used this library.

Dont delete the license headers present on code files.

Then you are fine to use it.

> Copyright 2012 Jake Wharton
>
> Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you
>   may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may
>   obtain a copy of the License at
>
> http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
>
> Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
>   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
>   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
>   implied. See the License for the specific language governing
>   permissions and limitations under the License.

Comment: `It means you have to mention in your application that you have used this library.` so you mean something like `powered by actionbar sherlock` ??  any ideas on how to do this more stylish?

Comment: VipulShah the mention need to be in the application or just in the comments on the code?

Comment: Do I need to mention it on Google Play Description or somewhere else explicitly in the application or somewhere implicitly.

Comment: It does not need to be displayed in your application afaik